# AWZ3 conversion not working

Tags: conversion, calibre, amazon

I'm attempting to convert a 26 meg `AZW3` file to `XML` or `HTML` or `TXT`.

I've tried a few online conversion sites, unfortunately they always fail with a very generic error message.

I've installed Calibre and am able to view the file using Calibre.  I've attempted to convert it to `TXT` from Calibre, but it was running for almost 48 hours and was stuck at 47%.

What do think is my best option for converting this `AZW3` file to any human readable format?

Calibre 1.25 
mac 10.9.1 2.93 GHz Intel Core i7 with 20 GB RAM

I am attempting to convert 26.8 meg `AZW` file to `TXT`, it's been running for over 48 hours now. It's said 47% complete since 1 minute after it started running.

```
Convert book 1 of 1 (World Almanac and Book of Facts 2014)
Resolved conversion options
calibre version: 1.25.0
{'asciiize': False,
'author_sort': None,
'authors': None,
'base_font_size': 0.0,
'book_producer': None,
'change_justification': u'original',
'chapter': u"//*[((name()='h1' or name()='h2') and re:test(., '\\s*((chapter|book|section|part)\\s+)|((prolog|pr ologue|epilogue)(\\s+|$))', 'i')) or @class = 'chapter']",
'chapter_mark': u'pagebreak',
'comments': None,
'cover': u'/var/folders/x7/fsp4tg0x5n1_r3m7svfljj2c0000gn/T/calibre_1.25.0_tmp_CZBMVW/nHYv70.jpeg',
'debug_pipeline': None,
'dehyphenate': True,
'delete_blank_paragraphs': True,
'disable_font_rescaling': False,
'duplicate_links_in_toc': False,
'embed_all_fonts': False,
'embed_font_family': None,
'enable_heuristics': False,
'expand_css': False,
'extra_css': None,
'filter_css': u'',
'fix_indents': True,
'font_size_mapping': None,
'force_max_line_length': False,
'format_scene_breaks': True,
'html_unwrap_factor': 0.4,
'inline_toc': False,
'input_encoding': None,
'input_profile': <calibre.customize.profiles.InputProfile object at 0x109fa7750>,
'insert_blank_line': False,
'insert_blank_line_size': 0.5,
'insert_metadata': False,
'isbn': None,
'italicize_common_cases': True,
'keep_color': False,
'keep_image_references': False,
'keep_ligatures': False,
'keep_links': False,
'language': None,
'level1_toc': None,
'level2_toc': None,
'level3_toc': None,
'line_height': 0.0,
'linearize_tables': False,
'margin_bottom': 5.0,
'margin_left': 5.0,
'margin_right': 5.0,
'margin_top': 5.0,
'markup_chapter_headings': True,
'max_line_length': 0,
'max_toc_links': 50,
'minimum_line_height': 120.0,
'newline': u'system',
'no_chapters_in_toc': False,
'no_inline_navbars': False,
'output_profile': <calibre.customize.profiles.KindleDXOutput object at 0x109fa7e10>,
'page_breaks_before': u"//*[name()='h1' or name()='h2']",
'prefer_metadata_cover': False,
'pretty_print': False,
'pubdate': None,
'publisher': None,
'rating': None,
'read_metadata_from_opf': u'/var/folders/x7/fsp4tg0x5n1_r3m7svfljj2c0000gn/T/calibre_1.25.0_tmp_CZBMVW/qDk0Mr.opf',
'remove_fake_margins': True,
'remove_first_image': False,
'remove_paragraph_spacing': False,
'remove_paragraph_spacing_indent_size': 1.5,
'renumber_headings': True,
'replace_scene_breaks': u'',
'search_replace': '[]',
'series': None,
'series_index': None,
'smarten_punctuation': False,
'sr1_replace': None,
'sr1_search': None,
'sr2_replace': None,
'sr2_search': None,
'sr3_replace': None,
'sr3_search': None,
'start_reading_at': None,
'subset_embedded_fonts': False,
'tags': None,
'timestamp': None,
'title': None,
'title_sort': None,
'toc_filter': None,
'toc_threshold': 6,
'txt_output_encoding': u'utf-8',
'txt_output_formatting': u'plain',
'unsmarten_punctuation': False,
'unwrap_lines': True,
'use_auto_toc': False,
'verbose': 2}
InputFormatPlugin: MOBI Input running
on /var/folders/x7/fsp4tg0x5n1_r3m7svfljj2c0000gn/T/calibre_1.25.0_tmp_CZBMVW/zJ7xqz.azw3
Found KF8 MOBI of type 'standalone'
Extracting text...
Parsing all content...
Parsing styles/0001.css ...
Parsing text/part0000.html ...
Parsing text/part0074.html ...
Parsing text/part0001.html ...
Parsing text/part0002.html ...
Parsing text/part0003.html ...
Parsing text/part0144.html ...
Parsing text/part0004.html ...
Parsing text/part0079.html ...
Parsing text/part0005.html ...
Parsing text/part0137.html ...
Parsing text/part0006.html ...
Parsing text/part0075.html ...
Parsing text/part0007.html ...
Parsing text/part0008.html ...
Parsing text/part0009.html ...
Parsing text/part0145.html ...
Parsing text/part0010.html ...
Parsing text/part0053.html ...
Parsing text/part0080.html ...
Parsing text/part0011.html ...
Parsing text/part0138.html ...
Parsing text/part0012.html ...
Parsing text/part0076.html ...
Parsing text/part0013.html ...
Parsing text/part0014.html ...
Parsing text/part0015.html ...
Parsing text/part0146.html ...
Parsing text/part0158.html ...
Parsing text/part0016.html ...
Parsing text/part0081.html ...
Parsing text/part0017.html ...
Parsing text/part0139.html ...
Parsing text/part0159.html ...
Parsing text/part0018.html ...
Parsing text/part0160.html ...
Parsing text/part0077.html ...
Parsing text/part0161.html ...
Parsing text/part0019.html ...
Parsing text/part0162.html ...
Parsing text/part0163.html ...
Parsing text/part0020.html ...
Parsing text/part0164.html ...
Parsing text/part0165.html ...
Parsing text/part0021.html ...
Parsing text/part0147.html ...
Parsing text/part0022.html ...
Parsing text/part0082.html ...
Parsing text/part0023.html ...
Parsing text/part0140.html ...
Parsing text/part0024.html ...
Parsing text/part0078.html ...
Parsing text/part0156.html ...
Parsing text/part0025.html ...
Parsing text/part0026.html ...
Parsing text/part0027.html ...
Parsing text/part0063.html ...
Parsing text/part0028.html ...
Parsing text/part0083.html ...
Parsing text/part0029.html ...
Parsing text/part0141.html ...
Parsing text/part0030.html ...
Parsing text/part0031.html ...
Parsing text/part0032.html ...
Parsing text/part0152.html ...
Parsing text/part0033.html ...
Parsing text/part0110.html ...
Parsing text/part0057.html ...
Parsing text/part0034.html ...
Parsing text/part0084.html ...
Parsing text/part0035.html ...
Parsing text/part0036.html ...
Parsing text/part0037.html ...
Parsing text/part0038.html ...
Parsing text/part0039.html ...
Parsing text/part0111.html ...
Parsing text/part0058.html ...
Parsing text/part0040.html ...
Parsing text/part0085.html ...
Parsing text/part0041.html ...
Parsing text/part0042.html ...
Parsing text/part0043.html ...
Parsing text/part0044.html ...
Parsing text/part0045.html ...
.html ...
Parsing text/part0154.html ...
Parsing text/part0054.html ...
Parsing text/part0157.html ...
Parsing text/part0055.html ...
Parsing text/part0056.html ...
Parsing text/part0114.html ...
Parsing text/part0061.html ...
Parsing text/part0088.html ...
Referenced file u'styles/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' not found
Reading TOC from NCX...
Merging user specified metadata...
Detecting structure...
Detected chapter: THE WORLD ALMANAC AND BOOK OF FACTS 2014
```

Comment: Did you make multiple attempts with Calibre or just the one failed attempt?

Comment: I let one attempt go for about 48 hours, I cancelled about 3 other attempts that went on for about an hour.  The thing that worried me is that multiple online conversion sites weren't able to convert it.  I guess I could have let it keep going, but how long should I wait?

Comment: I can't see it taking over an hour at most. I convert 1 and 2MB works in a couple minutes (mostly from EPUB to MOBI).  The conversion from AZW to MOBI should be easier because they are both Kindle formats.  Try converting to MOBI, if that works then convert the MOBI to one of your other choices.

Comment: I'll try MOBI.  Someone from calibre told me the record is 5 days to convert a file, I hope I don't break it.

Comment: I assume this is a free ebook, as otherwise you should not have uploaded it to a conversion site, can you share a link so I can download it and have a look?

Answer (score 3):

Calibre conversions usually do not that long. There are a few things you should try:

1. View the book in Calibre and flip through the pages. If the calibre viewer cannot handle that file, it is unlikely to be able to convert it.
2. Your output seems to be from the interactive conversion log, you should try the command-line conversion with [`ebook-convert`](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/cli/ebook-convert.html), the options might be a bit overwhelming, but the interesting ones are the ones for [debugging](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/cli/ebook-convert.html#debug):

   --debug-pipeline, -d

   ```
   Save the output from different stages of the conversion pipeline to the specified directory. Useful if you are unsure at which stage of the conversion process a bug is occurring.
   ```

   --verbose, -v

   ```
   Level of verbosity. Specify multiple times for greater verbosity.
   ```

   With those you can try to get some extra information on the process.
3. While converting keep an eye on processor load. This should not go down during the conversion progress. If it does hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,
   you will get a Python backtrace from the ebook-convert program, which might help you determining where the process is stuck.